# using GPU in Hyper-V virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm trying to run my Nvidia GPU in Hyper-V guest machine. I read that this can be done with RemoteFX from Hyper-V settings. The problem is that when I try to add my GPU to RemoteFX it say "this gpu does not meet the minimum requirements for RemoteFX". The only option, that can be chosen is my Intel GPU. So can someone tell what are the minmum requirements and why my Intel GPU can be used, but Nvidia GPU cannot? 
    I'm using windows 10 Enterprise, with GPU Nvidia GTX 850M and Intel i5 4200H with Intel HD Graphics 4600. My DirectX version is 12 and Driver model: WDDM 2.0.

Comment: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2013/11/05/gpu-requirements-for-remotefx-on-windows-server-2012-r2/

Comment: also did you follow this setup guide? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx#DirectX_11_compatible_graphic_adapter